# Bibliography for Seminorm Families and Induced Topology

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

When studying functional analysis, I read about families of semi-norms that induce a weaker topology that makes them continuous. I wanted to know if there is any good bibliography to study on this, and see examples, regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is good things about seminorms and seminormed spaces in "Topological Algebras
by V. K. Balachandran  (Author)".
You can download it. its free.